# Change value and id of radio button on change of radio button using js

Tags: javascript, ajax, calculator

Here I want user to change the radio button as per their choice and want to change the value and id of radio button to calculate the total value.
For now I checked default radio input it works for that, I need it works on change of radio button.

```js
const profit = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').value;
    const id = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').id;
    const principal = 10000;
    const time = id;
    const rate = profit/100;
    const n = 1;
    
    const compoundInterest = (p, t, r, n) => {
       const amount = p * (Math.pow((1 + (r / n)), t));
       return amount;
    };
    
    document.getElementById("total-amount").innerHTML = (compoundInterest(principal, time, rate, n));
```

```html
<input id="1" type="radio" class="months" value="8" checked="checked" name="rdmonths"/><span>12</span>
            <input id="2" type="radio" class="months" value="8" name="rdmonths"/><span>24</span>
            <input id="3" type="radio" class="months" value="8" name="rdmonths"/><span>36</span>
            <input id="4" type="radio" class="months" value="8" name="rdmonths"/><span>48</span>
            <input id="5" type="radio" class="months" value="8" name="rdmonths"/><span>60</span>
        <div style="float:right; width:45%; margin-bottom:50px;">
            <h2><b>Representative</b></h2>
            <p>Total Amount:<span id="total-amount" style="margin-left:30px;"></span></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a `click` event handler to each member of the `radio` group you can apply the same logic for each particular option. If this logic is within a function it makes it easier to call on subsequent `clicks`

```js
// apply the logic within a reusable function
const calculate_compount_interest=function(){
    const profit = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').value;
    const id = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').id;
    const principal = 10000;
    const time = id;
    const rate = profit/100;
    const n = 1;

    const compoundInterest = (p, t, r, n) => {
       const amount = p * (Math.pow((1 + (r / n)), t));
       return amount.toFixed(2);    // limit the result to a meaningful precision
    };

    document.getElementById("total-amount").innerHTML = (compoundInterest(principal, time, rate, n));   
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    // assign listener to each radio button
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="rdmonths"]').forEach( input=>{
        input.addEventListener('click', calculate_compount_interest )
    })
    // call on initial page-load
    calculate_compount_interest();
})
```

```html
<input id="1" type="radio" class="months" value="8" checked="checked" name="rdmonths"/><span>12</span>
<input id="2" type="radio" class="months" value="8" name="rdmonths"/><span>24</span>
<input id="3" type="radio" class="months" value="8" name="rdmonths"/><span>36</span>
<input id="4" type="radio" class="months" value="8" name="rdmonths"/><span>48</span>
<input id="5" type="radio" class="months" value="8" name="rdmonths"/><span>60</span>

<div style="float:right; width:45%; margin-bottom:50px;">
    <h2><b>Representative</b></h2>
    <p>Total Amount:<span id="total-amount" style="margin-left:30px;"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Professor can you go through this?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332605/magento-addeventlistener-on-change-radio-button-not-working-using-requirejs